# DateTime Parse error

Tags: c#

[This is the error. sam code parse same value in my other project, but not working in current project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq7vu.png)
Exception Type "System.FormatException" occurred in mscorlib.dll
 Additional info: string was not recognize as valide Date time

```
DateTime temp = DateTime.ParseExact(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Date/Time"].Value.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", null);
                DateTime tempnext = DateTime.ParseExact(dataGridView1.Rows[i + 1].Cells["Date/Time"].Value.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", null);
```

Comment: Post the code where you are getting an error

Comment: One can barely see anything on those small images. Use the debugger to inspect whatever value you're trying to parse when the exception is thrown.

Comment: @CaptainMagikarp  there you go... check it again

Comment: @VisualVincent i provide the code

Comment: You must still check what the input is when the exception is thrown, otherwise this is impossible to solve. Check the [**`Autos` window**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhawk8xd.aspx) or hover over the variable/property.

Comment: As the exception says, dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Date/Time"] value is not in proper format.

Comment: @CaptainMagikarp but same code is working in my another project for same dataGridview Value

Comment: @VisualVincent input just like this    13:1      actually this code runs very well in my another project but not working in this project for same input value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works in one project but not another, it could be a `Culture` issue.

You can try:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Date/Time"].Value.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Although you might want to consider `TryParse()` or `TryParseExact()`, in the case that this is just 1 invalid value that someone entered, so that the entire program doesn't break down.

Comment: thanx i hope i might be helpfull for me

Answer (score 1):

You're using *'DateTime.Parse**Exact**()'* with the format `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm`, but *your input* is `13:1` which would only be the format `HH:m` or `H:m`.

Because you're using `ParseExact` the input must be the in the ***exact same*** format as you've specified, so you would need an input like `05/03/2017 13:01` for it to work.

Consider using the regular [**`DateTime.Parse()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) or, as already suggested, [**`DateTime.TryParseExact()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) in order to verify the input without breaking the application.

Comment: sorry input is same as you mentioned like 14/10/2017 13:01. i just want to get 13:01 from input

Comment: @MuhammadHamza : Then we're back where we started. Are you sure that's the _**exact**_ input? Does it say so in the `Autos` window? -- I see you're using a different format from what I can make out of the screenshot. The current one in the question should work.

Comment: it was culture issue... by the way thanx... you're very helpfull

Comment: @MuhammadHamza : Well I'll be damned. But I don't see how that would affect an exact format...